# Tensor product of free R modules is $R^{mn}$

Tags: ring-theory, modules, free-modules

Let R be any ring (not commutative maybe).
Let $R^m$ and $R^n$ be considered as R-R bimodules.

> What is their tensor product as R-R bimodule?

I know as abelian groups it is $R^{mn}$. Is it also the same as R-R bimodule?

Comment: Don't tensor products always distribute over direct sums?

Comment: Yes. But the tensor product is an abelian group right? I'm asking if it's also isomorphic as R-R bimodule

Comment: Yes, it all goes through.